# Express.js send data to view not sent, What went wrong

Tags: jquery, node.js, express.io

I want to pass my products array to html page.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render(__dirname+ "/product.html",{data: Product_Array_fromDatabase});
})
```

At client side in HTML page am trying to view / will loop it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = JSON.stringify(data);
   alert(data) // Says Undefined
</script>
```

I am not getting value of data? Any help?

Comment: Are you even using any templating language like ejs or jade?

Comment: Add code snippet on http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io please!

Comment: @NomanUrRehman Yes, its ejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js i made the ejs to render the data and used jquery ajax to send the data to the page and alert it may be this will useful to you

**hello.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var engine = require('ejs-locals');

app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
res.render('index',{user:"John Smith"}) 
 });

app.get('/helo', function(req, res){
  res.send({'data':'hello'});
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

**index.ejs**
in the directory called views---path appname/views/index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("/helo", function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            var result = data
            alert(result['data'])
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
welcome <%= user%><br>
<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do we have to use same method after emit / broadcast? i.e. Loop using <%= %>... I am not much familiar with this tag... can we use  jquery/javascript just to loop?

Comment: <%= %> tag used to print varibles in the html page....in ejs..its a templating engine used in express.
<table>
<% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= data[i].id %></td>
     <td><%= data[i].name %></td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
</table>
if you want to loop thruogh the data do like this this example shows.inserting values in to the table..i hope this will help you